# How to get image/videos from Amazon Aws Bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3

How to get images/videos from Amazon Aws Bucket??
I have addedv some images & Videos into amazon aws bucket now i want to retrive those images.
mostly videos ..
How can i retrive it from bucket & show All list on page??
I'm using C#,Asp.net Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Amazon S3 .NET SDK and documentation for ListBucket request, it will return list of objects stored in the bucket.